# two divs top and bottom

Tags: html, css

div alignment one left next two top bottom last one right
it is nt coming like that when I'm doing

see this image

[image: http://i44.tinypic.com/10eejj8.jpg]

I would like to align the image like that with div tag, unfortunately when i aligned its not coming up like that,
 how do i leyout all the images inside one div tag>?

here is my html code

```
<div class="site_contents">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="big_logo"></div>
    <div class="work_nav"></div>
    <div class="testimonial"></div>
    <div class="cliants"></div>
    <div class="testimonial"></div>
    <div class="contact"></div>
  </div>
</div
```

here is my css code

```
.site_contents {
    height:auto;
    width: 900px;
    background-color: #666;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.header {
    background-color: #3CF;
    height: 262px;
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    border:2px solid #000;
}
.header div
{
    float: left;
}
.big_logo{
    background-color: #06C;
    height: 262px;
    width: 459px;
    background: url(images/sitetemplate_header.gif)  0 -21px;   
}
.work_nav {
    background-color: #F00;
    height: 159px;
    width: 170px;
}
.testimonial {
    background-color: #3F9;
    height: 104px;
    width: 170px;
}
.cliants {
    background-color: #09C;
    height: 262px;
    width: 171px;
}
.contact {
    background-color: #30C;
    height: 262px;
    width: 101px;
}
```

could any one help me please

Comment: @422 I don't need all div top bottom 
only two divs top bottom

Comment: Your English isn't the best, why not create a jsfiddle and screen pic of what u want to achieve

Comment: @422 I am new, not able to upload at the moment  :(

Comment: FYI:  Regarding your image... the word "clients" is not spelled with an "a".

Answer (score 1):

This is almost what you want. [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/w6BMj/)

You need to be careful about a number of things.

1. `work_nav` and `testimonial` need to be in a separate `div` which I have included (`container2`)
2. The total width needs to be adjusted. I have changed it as well. You can play with it to make it according to what you need.
3. I have included borders as well to recognize each box. You should remove those borders and the width taken by the borders must be subtracted from the total current width. That means adjust the current width again.

Comment: In you code you have testimonial 2, which I dont know where it goes in the image.